# Android not Downloading .html from web

Tags: android, html, save

im trying to save a remote web file (.html) inside my sdcard, so i can read it later or manipulate it, but the application crash in the start

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/paginas/index.html");
        //This LoadURL it load properly if i comment the img.DownloadFromURL, something is wrong there =/, if downloadfromurl is not commented, it crash!
        String url = "http://empregocerto.uol.com.br/info/vagas_por_area.html";

        ImageManager img = new ImageManager();
        img.DownloadFromUrl(url, "index.txt");

        //its ImageManager coz in the example the guy was downloading image, but i want all the html code in a file at my cellphone

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public class ImageManager {

        private final String PATH = "/data/data/com.helloandroid.downloader/";  //put the downloaded file here


        public void DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
                try {
                        URL url = new URL(imageURL); //you can write here any link
                        File file = new File(fileName);

                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
                        Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
                        Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
                        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
                        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                        /*
                         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                         */
                        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                        /*
                         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                         */
                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                        int current = 0;
                        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                                baf.append((byte) current);
                        }

                        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                        fos.close();
                        Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                                        + " sec");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
                }

        }
}
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

LOG CAT ERROR:

> 04-02 14:33:24.660: V/WebViewChromium(1370): Binding Chromium to the
>   main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b3d8e1c8} 04-02 14:33:24.680:
>   I/chromium(1370): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging
>   enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0 04-02 14:33:24.700:
>   I/BrowserProcessMain(1370): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
>   04-02 14:33:24.790: D/(1370): HostConnection::get() New Host
>   Connection established 0xb7df38f8, tid 1370 04-02 14:33:24.800:
>   W/chromium(1370): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled
>   because there is no system implementation 04-02 14:33:24.980:
>   D/dalvikvm(1370): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 6% free 2889K/3060K, paused
>   42ms, total 43ms 04-02 14:33:24.980: I/dalvikvm-heap(1370): Grow heap
>   (frag case) to 3.508MB for 635812-byte allocation 04-02 14:33:25.040:
>   D/dalvikvm(1370): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3510K/3684K, paused
>   50ms, total 50ms 04-02 14:33:25.350: D/dalvikvm(1370): GC_FOR_ALLOC
>   freed 13K, 3% free 3953K/4060K, paused 21ms, total 22ms 04-02
>   14:33:25.560: D/ImageManager(1370): download begining 04-02
>   14:33:25.560: D/ImageManager(1370): download
>   url:http://empregocerto.uol.com.br/info/vagas_por_area.html 04-02
>   14:33:25.560: D/ImageManager(1370): downloaded file name:index.txt
>
> //there is no file index.txt saved
>
> 04-02 14:33:25.750: D/dalvikvm(1370): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 4% free
>   4382K/4548K, paused 23ms, total 24ms 04-02 14:33:25.810:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(1370): Shutting down VM 04-02 14:33:25.810:
>   W/dalvikvm(1370): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0xb3accba8) 04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370): Process:
>   com.example.helloworld, PID: 1370 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 04-02 14:33:25.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.example.helloworld.MainActivity$ImageManager.DownloadFromUrl(MainActivity.java:87)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 04-02
>   14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   04-02 14:33:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1370):   ... 11 more 04-02
>   14:33:30.280: I/Process(1370): Sending signal. PID: 1370 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This means that you cannot run network type operations on the main UI thread. In your case, you are trying to retrieve web content over the network.

Therefore, `img.DownloadFromUrl(url, "index.txt");` must either be called in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or run in a separate thread.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/3286163) for a complete stackoverflow question and answers on this error.